# Bootstrap styles dont work on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I started to program with ruby on rails and I tried to import bootstrap to my Ruby On Rails and I tried to insert an navbar to my app and thats the result:
[Only text styles work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNir6.png)

As you can see only the text style works..

My Gemfile:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails' gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0' gem 'coffee-script-source', '~> 1.11', '>= 1.11.1'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api. gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console   gem 'byebug' end

group :development do   # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views   gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring   gem 'spring'
     gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'

end
```

My application.css.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
```

My application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

My application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Workspace</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true%>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>


<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try writing

```
//= require bootstrap.min
```

In your application.js

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
Try adding this in gemfile and run bundle and try again restarting the server

Comment: Add it or replace with gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'?

Comment: Looks like you css is fine.
Can you try removing 
`//= require bootstrap-sprockets`
And then add
`//= require bootstrap`
In your application.js

Answer (score 0):

You are using `bootstrap-sass`, so you need `sass-rails` gem. From the [*bootstrap-sass*](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

> In your Gemfile you need to add the bootstrap-sass gem, and ensure
>   that the sass-rails gem is present - it is added to new Rails
>   applications by default.

That said, add `gem sass-rails` in your `Gemfile`, then `bundle install` and restart the server

**Update:**

Also, you need to import `bootstrap-sprockets` **before** the `bootstrap`.

```
#application.css.scss
// "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: @OmerTaB Did you also tried my updated answer? Did you restarted the server too?

Comment: Yes and it dident change

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be the fact that you have the  gem 'bootstrap-sass' in the development group. This should go in the root of the Gemfile.